# What's the fastest/simplest way to create sea waves along a path in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

[image]

What's the fastest/simplest way to create sea waves along a path in illustrator?

I am looking for the best way to replicate something like the bottom left sea image (or top left img) in the picture above using illustrator.

I would do it by grouping a bunch of circles together but there's gotta be an easier way to do this

Comment: Why would a method that requires 1 minute of preparation be better than hitting ctrl+d for a half minute?

Comment: Maybe the wave line is just an example for the question. Remember the answers are not only for this OP, but for any other user. To create a specific waves line Cmd + D is enough. To frame a DIN A3 with quadruple wave lines, the one-minute tutorial will be more useful.

Comment: @Danielillo No, its no more or less work, just different. Its is best to learn that shortcuts are things that find you, looking for a shortcut for everything makes one unable to execute. There is a balance between the two. But i can do this quicker and simpler, but the level of abstraction is too great.

Answer (score 6):

- You can make a **Pattern Brush** with a semicircle and apply it to a line
- Fill = None / Stroke = Black
- On the **Pattern Brush Window Options** choose **Method > Tints**, to enable the color change of the brush stroke

[image: brus01]

- Make a **Pattern Brush** with a square cropped by a semicircle on the top for the second option
- Fill = Black / Stroke = none
- Brush **Method** > **Tints**
- Duplicate the line and change the stroke color

[image]